# workaround for column specification in select clause not having intellisense in ssms till your specify the table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, intellisense, ssms

In ssms, intellisense doesn't kick when specifying column names in select until afteryou specify the table name in the from clause.

This makes sense cuz ssms can't read your mind.

However it is a pain in the neck because we write the select clause before the from clause.

I am not able to perfectly verbalize what i am looking for but what would be ideal is to be able to specify the from clause before the select clause.

I don't want every single column in the database to be in the list obviously.

The way one typically writes a sql statement is kind of weird and unwieldy, with select clause coming before the 'from' clause thus depriving us of the advantage of intellisense, unless we go back to column list after you write from 'tablename'. Just feels weird and annoying and there has to be a better way

Comment: So what do you want? Every single column in your database to be in the list from the start? What if you have `EmployeeID` in 40 different tables? What if you don't even know what columns are in the table you're after? This requirement doesn't make any sense to me at all. Just type `SELECT FROM dbo.tablename` and then go back to the column list.

Comment: I don't want every single column in the database to be in the list obviously. I was just pointing out that the way one typically writes a sql statement is kind of weird and unwieldy, with select clause coming before from column thus depriving us of the advantage of intellisense, unless we do what you say which is go back to column list after you write from 'tablename'. Just feels weird and annoying and there has to be a better way

Comment: Well quite frankly the way the SQL language is constructed was decided decades before IntelliSense was ever even a concept. There is no "better way" unless you want to write your own parser for T-SQL that will parse something like `FROM dbo.table SELECT ...`. I agree with you that that would be a more natural way to write queries, but that doesn't make it possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the way SQL Server parses a `SELECT` statement. You can, however, change how you write it. Just write:

```
FROM dbo.tablename
```

Then move your cursor *above* that, and type `SELECT` and then you will have IntelliSense.

Another really hacky and bad idea would be:

```
;WITH x AS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tablename)
SELECT ... FROM x;
```

But this is really bad news *and* you still have to type all of that stuff before Management Studio can read your mind.

Sorry, but you're looking for an answer that doesn't exist.

Comment: lol. the 'from' clause coming before 'select' clause is what we have in c# linq. Such a pity we don't have the same in ssms.

Comment: @JayJayJay the order of clauses in a SELECT statement has nothing to do with SSMS. C# LINQ re-writes your query for you - SSMS doesn't do that. The query they both send to the server still has to conform to the standard, not the format that would be slightly more convenient for you.